# Read sms from Mobile device with .net application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, c#-3.0

Can anyone help me?

How can I read SMS from mobile with my .net application? i have a Nokia 5310 mobile phone. Can you tell me from where i can download Nokia SDK or source code or Nokia API etc?

I want to make a custom application which reads SMS and at the same time sends a response to the sender's mobile number.

Answer (score 1):

Check out qt.nokia.com.
From what I understand Nokia bought QT which allows for multiplatform development since Nokia phones don't use a standard software platform.